# I have a problem in the position of the maximum and minimum, check the program below please

Tags: arrays, c, position, max, min

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

            int main () {
            int MIN,MAX,j,k;
            int e,i,T[100],f=0;
```

\ Here to enter the dimension of my array

```
            printf("Entrez la dimension de votre tableau ne depasser pas 100 : \n");
             scanf("%d",&e);
```

\ here to let the user complete, the array

```
            if (e>100 || e<=0)
             { printf("Veuillez entrez une dimension valide");
                return 0; }

                 for(i=0;i<e;i++) {
                   printf("T[%d]=",i);
                     scanf("%d",&T[i]);
                     }
```

\ here to show the values stored in my array

```
                  printf("  Les elements du tableau sont:");
                   for(i=0;i<e;i++) {
                     printf(" %d  ",T[i]);
                       }

                    MAX=T[0];
                    MIN=T[0];
```

The problem is concerning the position, of my maximum, it shows the dimension of the array chosen by the user, since it's the same variable used
I thought of storing the variable in another one but doesn't work
You can observe above, there are some variables not used, I thought of using them to solve the problem, but doesn't seem like it worked

```
                     for(i=0;i<e;i++) {
                      if (T[i]>MAX) {
                         MAX=T[i];
                                   }
                                         }
                       printf("\n  Le maximum est: %d et occupe la 
                              position: %d \n",MAX,i);
```

\ the second loop to find the minimum in my array
\ my problem is in the position of my maximum or minimum since it's the same

```
           for(i=0;i<e;i++) {
                 if (T[i]<MIN) {
                          MIN=T[i];
                                    } }
              printf("\n  Le minimum est: %d et occupe la position: %d \n",MIN,i);

                      return 0;
                                 }
```

Comment: Please format your question and your code properly. Read this: [ask] and why you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Don't use capitalised identifiers for variable names. Those are usually for constants and macros. In fact, `MIN` and `MAX`  are macros defined in `sys/param.h`, which is commonly included in code or header files.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't save the index that resulted in the max value(same for min). Therefore `i` will always be equal to `e` at the end of the loop.

```
int MaxPos = 0
for(i=0;i<e;i++) {
    if (T[i]>MAX) {
        MAX=T[i];
        MaxPos = i
    }
}
//Note that if we got here, then i = e
printf("\n  Le maximum est: %d et occupe la position: %d \n",MAX,MaxPos);
```

Comment: Ah right, thanks it worked!

Answer (score 1):

After the both for loops the variable `i` is equal to the value of the variable `e` due to the form of the loops

```
for(i=0;i<e;i++)
```

Pay attention to that it is enough to have one for loop to find the minimum and the maximum. And it is enough to track only positions of the maximum and the minimum because knowing a position you can always get the value stored in an array at  this position.

For example

```
MAX = 0;
MIN = 0;

for ( i = 1; i < e; i++ )
{
    if ( T[MAX] < T[i] )
    {
        MAX = i;
    }
    else if ( T[i] < T[MIN] )
    {
        MIN = i;
    }
}

printf("\n  Le maximum est: %d et occupe la position: %d \n", T[MAX], MAX);
printf("\n  Le minimum est: %d et occupe la position: %d \n", T[MIN], MIN);
```

Comment: Still didn't get it why would I initialize max with 0? It's working perfectly fine with max=T[0] and then the loop starts comparing, easy!  Well concerning your version of the program I checked it's working just fine too, thanks!

Comment: @Joê-sephAb In your code you initialized MAX and MIN with the values of the first element of the array. that is of the element at index 0 If to track indices instead of values then you need initially to set MAX and MIN as indices to 0. See the calls of printf and how MIN and MAX are used. They are used as indices that points to the minimum and maximum values.

Answer (score -2):

You have bad choice also of initial values, apart from not keeping the position:

> ```
> MAX=T[0];
> MIN=T[0];
> ```

When you search for maximum you initial value should be the minimum value possible MAX=INT_MIN;. The real value is -2147483647 - 1. In same way your initial value for minimum should be MIN = INT_MAX, the real value is 2147483647.
When your values are properly initialized, then you will have correct results.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why this initialization won't work?.. The only thing that it does is that he can start from `i=1` now.

Comment: if you take for example the proposed code
    if (T[i]>MAX) {
       MAX=T[i];
        MaxPos = i
    }

and if the values in T are ordered in a way that never respects the check
for example 10, 9,8, because of the choice to have first value to be the max value, you will never enter the statements in the brakets because they are equal, so in order to know that you will every time pass throuth code for selecting max, it is better to have value that will guarantee that check for max is true

Comment: You are correct, in this case the `if` statement will never be true. Why is this wrong though? If that's the case, then `T[0]` indeed had the maximum value, and `MAX` will contain this value and `MaxPos` will be 0.

Comment: I am talking about how it should be done in order to avoid errors. If you do it in right way, you will always expect good results. In this simple case, there is not big matter, but it is error prone, if there was more code in if statement brackets.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree. If you use `MAX = INT_MIN`, then after the first iteration of the loop this is exactly what will happen. `MAX = T[0]` and `MaxPos = 0`. Please show me an example where this can fail.

Comment: @Hristo Bojkov Your approach is bad because it is not a general. You will be unable to write a general function for any integer type or the function will be too complicated and error prone.

Comment: I only said that if you select the first value, you will never pass through the code for selecting maximum value...and may miss some code that is executed there. depends on the requirement of the app itself, this app shows only the first maximum, what about the last one, or what about to count them, any way we do not have enough info.